# Creating a dictionary with a tuple as value by reusing another function

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am writing a function that returns a dictionary with the year of the docs as key and, as value, it specifies a tuple, that is returned by `do_get_citations_per_year` function.

```
def do_get_citations_per_year(data, year):
    result = tuple()
    my_ocan['creation'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_ocan['creation']).year

    len_citations = len(my_ocan.loc[my_ocan["creation"] == year, "creation"])
    timespan = my_ocan.loc[my_ocan["creation"] == year, "timespan"].fillna(0).mean()

    result = (len_citations, timespan)
    print(result)


    return result
#test print(my_ocan.get_citations_per_year(2018)) Output: (32, 240.03125)
```

When I call the same function inside another one: `do_get_citations_all_years` function it does not return me the same tuple `(32, 240.03125)` but instead it returns `(0, nan)`. Why is going on there?

```
def do_get_citations_all_years(data):
    mydict = {}
    s = set(my_ocan.creation)
    print(s)
    for year in s:
        mydict[year] = do_get_citations_per_year(data, year)

    return mydict
#Output: {2016: (0, nan), 2017: (0, nan), 2018: (0, nan), 2013: (0, nan), 2015: (0, nan)}
```

Thank you very much in advance =)

Comment: IIUC, `my_ocan.groupby(pd.to_datetime(my_ocan['creation']).dt.year).agg({'timespan': ['size', 'mean']}).apply(tuple, 1).to_dict()` ..?